# Where to start when programming OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I am trying my hand at OpenGL, but have come up short so far.

Any ideas or tips where to start.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From online resources I know:

- [An intro to modern OpenGL](http://duriansoftware.com/joe/An-intro-to-modern-OpenGL.-Table-of-Contents.html)
- [Learning Modern 3D Graphics Programming](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/)
- [open.gl](http://open.gl)

Stay away from outdated stuff like NeHe tutorials.

Comment: @SirDigbyChickenCaesar They're not fixed function (hint fixed function is deprecated and tutorials using it are not good).

Comment: If anybody interested in running the Learning Modern 3D Graphics Programming tutorials on OS X, I have an Xcode+GLFW3 port here: https://github.com/rsanchezsaez/gltut-glfw (wip)